# Why is my IdentitySet only showing the last item?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas series and iterating over all items. Each loop I check if an entry already exists and add them one-by-one to a sqlalchemy session if no entry was found. After the loop is finished I want to retrieve the amount of items I added to the session before commiting. However it only shows 1 Item in the IdentitySet. When commiting the session all items get inserted to my database.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import Series
from random import randint
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from .models import Alarm

engine = create_engine(...)
session = Session(engine)

series = Series(data=[randint(1, 10**3) for i in range(0, 12)],
                index=[datetime(2020, i, 1) for i in range(1, 13)])

series.count()  # Returns 12

for index, value in series.iteritems():
    alarm = session.query(Alarm).filter_by(date=index.date()).first()  # Returns None
    if alarm:
        continue
    alarm = Alarm(date=index.date(), value=value)
    session.add(alarm)

len(session.new)  # Returns 1
session.commit()  # Inserts 12 entries to database
```

Comment: Can you add a var dump of series?

Comment: Added some dummy data and import statements

Comment: What do you see if you `print(session.new)` immediately after you call `len(session.new)`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/sYShWe3F) works fine for me.

Comment: Yes your right! I've tested it again and it works as expected. The problem seems to be the first query, which I commented out because I thought it wont be the problem...

After adding alarm to session and afterwards setting alarm to None in the next loop seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `echo=True` to your `create_engine()` call and look at the SQL being emitted you will notice that the rows are being inserted into the table one at a time as you iterate through the loop. That's because the `session.query()` is performing an implicit flush of the session to ensure it is getting the most up-to-date information (e.g., as might be necessary in a multi-user environment).

So all 12 items are being inserted but the session never has more than one new element at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to be that you can't overwrite the same variable after adding it to a session.

```py
alarm = Alarm(date=date(2020, 12, 31), value=123)
session.add(alarm)
len(session.new)  # Returns 1

alarm = None
len(session.new)  # Returns 0
```

So this should fix my problem:

```py
alarms = []
for index, value in series.iteritems():
    alarm = session.query(Alarm).filter_by(date=index.date()).first()
    if alarm:
        continue
    alarms.append(Alarm(date=index.date(), value=value))
session.add_all(alarms)
```

Is there a better way of doing this without the list `alarms`?